# Showing onclick selection and only allowing one to be selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the bottom of my webpage, I have 4 divs that change colors when hovered:

```
<div class="icon">
     <img id="AboutUs" src="Image1.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> About Us </p>
</div>
<div class="icon">
     <img id="Something1" src="Image2.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> Something </p>
</div>
<div class="icon">
     <img id="Something2" src="Image3.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> Something </p>
</div>
<div class="icon">
     <img id="Something3" src="Image4.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> Something </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon:hover
{background-color:grey;}
```

From here, I want to be able to click on one of the divs so the background changes to a darker shade while also only allowing one div to be selected at a time. I'm not sure where to go from here, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Do you want to solve it by a html form or by javascript?

Comment: You should look into Javascript, using an if statement and setting the DOM background is pretty easy. Post more if you need help! If this is for prototype purposes there are ways to just show this using css :target

Comment: HTML, CSS or javascript are all fine. I never learned JQuery though

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon">
     <img id="AboutUs" src="Image1.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> About Us </p>
</div>
<div class="icon">
     <img id="Something1" src="Image2.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> Something </p>
</div>
<div class="icon">
     <img id="Something2" src="Image3.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> Something </p>
</div>
<div class="icon">
     <img id="Something3" src="Image4.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
     <p> Something </p>
</div>

<style>
.icon:hover
{background-color:grey;}
</style>

<script>
var clicked = false;
  $('.icon').click(function(){
    if(clicked==false){
     
      clicked = true;
      $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
    }
  })
  
</script>
```